# CollectionViewSource sorting stops working in DataGrid when DataContext is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, collectionviewsource

I have a collection of a class "Widget" that has properties Name (string) and Rank (int).  I am creating a CollectionViewSource instance in my view model that declares the sort order by Rank and then by Name.  In my view model constructor I am creating three widgets where the order resulting from Rank is opposite of the order resulting from Name.

Here is my main view model code:

```cs
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private void FirePropertyChanged(string property)
   {
      if (null != PropertyChanged)
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
   }

   private CollectionViewSource _widgetView;

   public CollectionViewSource WidgetView
   {
      get { return _widgetView; }
      set { _widgetView = value; }
   }

   public MainViewModel()
   {
      WidgetView = new CollectionViewSource();
      WidgetView.IsLiveSortingRequested = true;
      WidgetView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Rank", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
      WidgetView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
      WidgetView.Source = new ObservableCollection<Widget>()
      {
         new Widget() { Name = "W_1", Rank = 3 },
         new Widget() { Name = "W_2", Rank = 2 },
         new Widget() { Name = "W_3", Rank = 1 },
      }; ;
   }
}
```

And my MainWindow.xaml looks like this.

```xml
<Window x:Class="CollectionViewSortingBug.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CollectionViewSortingBug"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
      <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="New View Model" Name="newViewModelButton" Click="newViewModelButton_Click" />
      <DataGrid Name="dgv" ItemsSource="{Binding WidgetView.View}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Rank}" Header="Rank" />
         </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And the code behind the window for the click handler is this:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void newViewModelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      DataContext = new MainViewModel();
   }
}
```

And, finally, here is the Widget.cs code:

```cs
class Widget : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private void FirePropertyChanged(string property)
   {
      if (null != PropertyChanged)
         PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
   }

   private string _name;

   public string Name
   {
      get { return _name; }
      set
      {
         _name = value;
         FirePropertyChanged("Name");
      }
   }

   private int _rank;

   public int Rank
   {
      get { return _rank; }
      set
      {
         _rank = value;
         FirePropertyChanged("Rank");
      }

   }
}
```

As you can see, when I click the button a new MainViewModel is constructed and the MainWindow's DataContext is assigned to that new instance.  The first time I click the button everything works as expected and this is in my table:

```
| Name | Rank |
|------|------|
| W_3  | 1    |
| W_2  | 2    |
| W_1  | 3    |
```

And if I edit the Rank value the rows will move accordingly.  For example if I set W_2's Rank to 10 it will move below W_1.  If I set all Rank values equal and then change the name the table will sort alphabetically by the new name as expected.

But, if I click the button again the table is now sorted by name instead.

```
| Name | Rank |
|------|------|
| W_1  | 3    |
| W_2  | 2    |
| W_3  | 1    |
```

And changing the Rank *or* name values has no effect.  It is as if all sorting logic is cleared out and live sorting no longer happens at all.

Why is the behavior different when the DataContext changes?

UPDATE:
I replaced the DataGrid with an ItemsControl with similar function (TextBox for Name and Rank) and it continues to sort as I have intended it to with the CollectionViewSource (i.e. it is not exhibiting this problem).  All other code is the same.  Here is what I replaced the DataGrid block with:

```xml
<ItemsControl Name="ic" ItemsSource="{Binding WidgetView.View}" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Widget}">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Width="100"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Rank}"  Width="75"/>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Oddly, if I leave *both* controls in there (stacked in the DockPanel) then things break again for *both* controls.  Could this be an actual bug?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get it to work, although it feels more like a work-around than a proper answer.

If I remove the following two lines from the `MainViewModel` constructor:

```cs
WidgetView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Rank", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
WidgetView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

And instead add the `SortDescriptions` in the click handler in the MainWindow.xaml.cs then I get the expected behavior.  Now my click handler method looks like this:

```cs
private void newViewModelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var mvm = new MainViewModel();
    DataContext = mvm;
    mvm.WidgetView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Rank", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    mvm.WidgetView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
```

And for some reason that works on the first click and on all subsequent clicks; the table updates as I expect and the order changes when I modify `Rank` and/or `Name` accordingly.  I still don't understand why it works the first time but then fails after subsequent clicks if `SortDescriptions` is updated in the constructor.

My theory is that perhaps there is some kind of binding in the `DataGrid` that will trigger if the `SortDescriptions` collection changes and that triggering causes the sorting to work.  Therefore, if `SortDescriptions` does not change after the `DataContext` is set then the `DataGridView` somehow misses the fact that it should be sorting.  To test this theory I changed the code back to have the `SortDescriptions` added in the constructor and then added a new `SortDescription` based on a non-existent property "Foo" in the click handler after the `DataContext` assignment.  This *also* fixed the problem (though it is not what I'd recommend as a final fix).